# Cannot Execute binary file used to SSH into school computer

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to execute the following script file on my Macbook through the terminal in order to gain access to a school resource. However, each time I try to execute the file I get the following error: `cannot execute binary file`. Here are the contents of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

UG_NUM=$1 PORT=$(($2 + 5900))

echo "Connecting to port :$PORT on ug$UG_NUM"

ssh -L $PORT:127.0.0.1:$PORT somestudent@ug$UG_NUM.eecg.toronto.edu
```

Comment: Have you checked if the file is executable? You can go to the directory the fire is on and run `$ ls -l`

Comment: Yes I have, "-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 user  staff  10398  4 Feb 17:51 ugssh.s"

Comment: And the arguments that you are using as port and UG_NUMBER are valid?

Comment: What happens if you just run the SSH command by itself? The script doesn't look terribly useful.

Comment: `ugssh.s` is 10398 bytes while the script you posted is 159 bytes. It sounds like you've got the wrong file.